# Use Excel table row names as variable names in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a simple Excel table with two columns. After importing the table into MATLAB, I want the names from column 1 to be declared as variables with corresponding values from column 2.

So in MATLAB, it would look like this:

```
House = "Villa"
Street = "Grand avenue"
Number = 88
Country = "US"
```

Example below:

[image: Example below]

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `assignin` for something like this:

```matlab
function assignin_me(name, value)
assignin('caller', name, value)
end
```

Then you can loop over your table `t` like:

```matlab
for i = 1:size(t,1)
   assignin_me(t{i,1}, t{i,2});
end
```

But I would also reconsider storing these values directly in variables anyway. You might have better luck just sticking them in fields in a struct:

```matlab
s = struct;
for i = 1:size(t,1)
   s.(t{i,1}) = t{i,2};
end
```

Comment: Many thanks Andrew! I used your suggestion of struct. Only thing I needed to add was converting it to a character array. Works as expected.

s = struct;
for i = 1:size(t,1)
   s.(char(t{i,1})) = char(t{i,2});
end